# GitHub repository older than GitHub itself?

Tags: git, github

I am just curious.

The initial [commit](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp/commits/master) of this [repository](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) dates from `27 Sep 2006`.

How is that even possible when GitHub itself started development in `1 October 2007` and was launched in `April 2008` (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git, the version control system, is separate from GitHub, which is just one of the ways you can host a Git repository. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), Git was released back in 2005. I assume this Git repository was created on someone's local machine (and maybe hosted somewhere other than GitHub) until sometime after GitHub was launched, at which point the hosting was moved to GitHub.

Comment: Yes, that's probably it indeed.

Comment: @old_mountain In addition, you can edit the date of a commit. There's no stopping you making commits in the 1990s.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [@jackel414's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41269508/14660) that Git predates Github, the date on a Git commit does not have to be the current date. Remember, the date is the date the commit was made, not when it was uploaded to Github.

While it can easily happen if the system clock is wrong, and similar mistakes, there's a number of reasons this might be done deliberately.

One is to reflect the date a patch was submitted, like a patch received via email, using `git commit --date` and probably also `--author`.

Another is because the commit was imported from another version control system. For example, [the Test::More repository begins on March 28, 2001](https://github.com/Test-More/test-more/commits/47db98db3017eae991580176bbbe91e55b6db8e9). This repository started with RCS, switched to CVS (internally the same as RCS), then [from CVS to Aegis](https://github.com/Test-More/test-more/commits/6acb88f10c0bb9f527783e46f114c1de2169ba6d), [back to CVS](https://github.com/Test-More/test-more/commits/a2ba54d1f6a6a8e669b27be28c4d3e3a08a35761), then [SVK](https://github.com/Test-More/test-more/commits/b648862a0cc64fe7bdd91d2d7c43ad4651fc8380) (which is SVN under the hood), and [finally Git](https://github.com/Test-More/test-more/commits/6a9116cf457012cfbcd620d31ac3956f21ed8a5b). Only in [Jan 2009 was it uploaded to Github](https://github.com/Test-More/test-more/commits/ad64d622ee32f9432b7d885c37465f9b99e09ba2).